# Is it possible to add QWidget to layout but don't remove with parent?

Tags: qt, qt5

I don't want my widget to be deleted automatically with parent - is it possible?

Maybe it's possible to add widget to layout without setting parent?

If I do `widget->setParent(nullptr);` after adding to layout my widget simply doesn't appear :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Qt widgets, the notion of parent/child is tightly coupled with the way widgets are drawn an displayed on screen. You cannot have a widget in the layout of another widget without having them being child and parent.

Now if what you want is only to prevent the child widget (or any class inheriting QObject) to be deleted when its parent is deleted, you could listen to the `QObject::destroyed()` signal on the parent and remove the parent/child relationship when the signal fires (be sure to use direct or blocking connection).